# Dictionary Key Sorting

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

Hi i have an dictionary which is been set by me and am accessing it 
the code is as follows.

```
NSMutableDictionary* filteredDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [filteredDictionary setObject:@"xcode" forKey:@"1"];
    [filteredDictionary setObject:@"ios" forKey:@"3"];
    [filteredDictionary setObject:@"ipad" forKey:@"2"];
    [filteredDictionary setObject:@"iphone" forKey:@"5"];
    [filteredDictionary setObject:@"simulator" forKey:@"4"];

   NSLog(@"%@",filteredDictionary);
```

current output:

```
{

1 = xcode;
2 = ipad;
3 = ios;
4 = simulator;
5 = iphone;    
}
but i want 
{
1 = xcode;
3 = ios;
2 = ipad;
5 = iphone;
4 = simulator;
}
```

i want the dictionary as i set the object in it

i dont want to make the dictionary to sort according to it

Pls Help

Thanks in advance.....

Comment: this will help you [Old Question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8215038/2407907)

Answer (score 1):

You can't sort the keys in-place, as dictionaries are hash-tables.

You can get the key/value pairs as an array, and sort the array before showing it though:

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/4558777/15721

Answer (score 1):

The NSDictionary doesn't remember the order in which you add the keys.  You'll have to do it yourself.  I would suggest using an [NSMutableOrderedSet](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSMutableOrderedSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSMutableOrderedSet).

```
NSMutableDictionary* filteredDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
NSMutableOrderedSet* keyOrder = [[NSMutableOrderedSet alloc] init];

[filteredDictionary setObject:@"xcode" forKey:@"1"];
[keyOrder addObject: @"1"];
[filteredDictionary setObject:@"ios" forKey:@"3"];
[keyOrder addObject: @"3"];

// etc
```

Obviously this is a pain in the neck, so create yourself a new collection class

```
@implementation MyMutableOrderedDictionary
{
     NSMutableDictionary* filteredDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
     NSMutableOrderedSet* keyOrder = [[NSMutableOrderedSet alloc] init];

}

-(void) setObject: (id) object forKey: (id <NSCopying>) key
{
    [filteredDictionary setObject: object forKey: key];
    [keyOrder addObject: key]; 
} 
-(NSOrderedSet*) keys
{
    return keyOrder;
}

// Some other methods

@end
```

You can implement some enumeration methods by iterating over `keyOrder`  internally or over the `keys` property externally.

Note I'm not subclassing NSMutableDictionary, because that can be a pain in the arse as it is a class cluster.

Answer (score 0):

NSDictonary doesn't guarantee order when you access it. You have to use NSArray if you want to keep order of elements.

There few ideas like OrderedDictionary (http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/12/ordereddictionary-subclassing-cocoa.html) but it's better to just use right objects for right purposes.

Answer (score 0):

NSDictonary is not mean to sort the objects and it is absolutely unimportant to consider the order of the elements.
NSdictonary is a set of key-value pair where it is expected to access the value using the respective key and so the concept of `index` is not useful in it.
Still if you want to play on indexes you should use NSArray.